# Go or Rust library to use Monero

Tags: blockchain, light-wallet, library

Is there any library for Go (Golang) or Rust that I can use in order to generate the key pair,  manually build a transaction, sign it and broadcast it to a remote node?

I searched GitHub and either the libraries are unmaintained / don't have all this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally two approaches to getting Monero functionality into other languages: 1) to make use of the JSON-RPC interfaces and 2) building Monero source files and creating bindings. The former is the simplest and easiest to maintain. The latter gives more fine grained control but requires thought for portability.

Jumping back to your requirements:

> generate key pair, manually build a transaction, sign it and broadcast it to a remote node

Generating keys is fairly simple and can be done without a "monero" library.

Manually building a transaction is not as simple. This requires a running node and wallet file. This is because you will need (amongst other things) to select inputs and outputs. Using the JSON-RPC interface is definitely the best route for this.

Comment: Indeed is the easiest option, but querying a remote node about the utxo is doable. much appreciate your help.

Comment: "but querying a remote node about the utxo is doable" - yes, for which you would be using the RPC interface. Pretty much every "library" there is for Monero just wraps the JSON-RPC interface. That interface doesn't change frequently (or rather have breaking changes) which is probably why any library using it are not updated that often.